# Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an order in a quadratic field $K$. Prove that $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathcal{O}_K$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I'm working with this definition:
[image]

I know that $\mathcal{O}$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module with two generators. Also, i figured out that the inclusion is true if and only if the two generators are algebraic integers. But how can i prove that, if they can be any $\alpha, \beta \in K$ as long as $1 \in \alpha \mathbb{Z} + \beta \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\alpha \in K$ is an algebraic integer iff $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: I really tried to figure out what is the idea. I don't know if $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]$ is finitely generated, because for now I just know it is in $K$. How to proceed?